# Realm Error No Subscription for WRITE: When doing multiple subscriptions of different type

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, realm, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to configure the realm with the help of the below function. Initially, there was only EmailAccount class after adding ApplicationAccount class while writing to EmailAccount cluster it is working but for ApplicationAccount it is saying **Cannot write to class ApplicationAccount when no flexible sync subscription has been created.**

How to solve this ??

```
override fun configureTheRealm() {
        if (user != null) {
            val config = SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, setOf(EmailAccount::class, ApplicationAccount::class))
                .initialSubscriptions { sub ->
                    add(
                        query = sub.query<EmailAccount>("ownerId == $0", user.id),
                        name = "User's EmailAccounts"
                    )
                    add(
                        query = sub.query<ApplicationAccount>("ownerId == $0", user.id),
                        name = "User's Application Account"
                    )
                }
                .log(LogLevel.ALL)
                .build()
            realm = Realm.open(config)
            Log.d("USERID", "$user")
        }
    }
```

I have already tried terminating the sync and then enabling it again. But the same error is happening.

Comment: What's being done with `query =`? Does it behave the same with `add(sub.query<...`?

Comment: yes I have specified it explicitly because I also want to add the name for the subscription

Comment: I also have the same problem, did you fix it?

Comment: Not yet :( @Ashman

Answer (score 0):

I might ran into a similar issue like you. In my case I used a template app using Mongo DeviceSync with an already defined scheme.
It was working as intended, then I tried to extend the give template by adding more schemes and write some data according to that newly defined scheme into the database.
I'm sure my initial subscription was set up correctly (similar to yours but with empty query to get any objects of the given Scheme), but when writing into the realm I got the same Error as you did. After some more testing I found the following in my logs:

```
2024-03-24 14:52:24.599 17968-18031 REALM  com.mongodb.app  W  [Sdk] Client reset: manual reset required for Realm in '/data/user/0/com.mongodb.app/files/mongodb-realm/mundguttest-dzyhi/65fe7ef60e4fa01f99d57222/default.realm'
2024-03-24 14:52:24.600 17968-18009 REALM  com.mongodb.app  W  [Sdk] Client reset: manual reset required for Realm in '/data/user/0/com.mongodb.app/files/mongodb-realm/mundguttest-dzyhi/65fe7ef60e4fa01f99d57222/default.realm.fresh'
```

I deleted the folder containing both folders which yields in Exceptions, when starting the app. But after uninstalling and installing it works as intended, so that I can write data according to my new schemes are successfully written to db.

I hope that helps you as well.